# Windows Update obsessed with updates for software I've long since uninstalled

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update

I have a Vista SP2 laptop that came with the demo version of Office 2007, which I eventually uninstalled. I naively did this at a time when Windows Update had available updates for Office 2007 in its list. Now Windows Update can't let go of those updates. I understand that I did something I should not have done.

If I let it try to install the updates, the whole install fails for everything.

The alternative is to go down the list and uncheck each of the unwanted updates, which I can do, but I'd rather not have to do that every single time I do updates.

Is there a solution to this, or have I screwed myself incurably? Linux is not an option, I use the machine for Windows development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps when you ran the uninstaller it did not remove everything, leading Windows Update to believe you still have it installed. Perhaps try the suggestions on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928218

EDIT: Also, in Vista, I believe you can right click on an update and click "Hide".

Comment: The right click worked. Boy do I feel stupid for not trying that! Thanks!